# How to generate sparse orthogonal matrix in python?

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, orthogonal

How can one generate **random** *sparse* orthogonal matrix?

I know there is a sparse matrices in scipy library but they are generally non-orthogonal. One can exploit QR-factorization, but it is not necessarily preserves sparsity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a preliminary thought you could partition the matrix into diagonal blocks, fill those blocks with QR and then permute rows/columns. The resulting matrices will remain orthagonal. Alternatively, you could define some sparsity pattern for `Q` and try to minimize `f(Q, xi)`  subject to `QQ^T=I`  where `f` is some (preferably) convex function that adds entropy through the random variable `xi`. Can't say anything about the efficacy of either method since I haven't actually tried them.

EDIT: A bit more about the second method. `f` can really be any function. One choice might be similarity of the non-zero elements to a random gaussian vector (or any other random variate): `f = ||vec(Q) - x||_2^2, x ~ N(0, sigma * I)`. You could handle this using any general constrained optimizer. The problem of course, is that not every pattern `S` is guaranteed to have a (full rank) orthogonal filling. If you have the memory, L1 regularization (or a smooth approximation) could encourage sparsity in a dense matrix variable: `g(Q) = f(Q) + P(Q)` where `P` is any sparsity-inducing penalty function. Check out Wen & Yen (2010) "A feasible Method for Optimization with Orthogonality Constraints" for an algorithm specifically designed for optimization of general (differentiable) functions over (dense) orthogonal matrices and Liu, Wu, So (2015) "Quadratic Optimization with Orthogonality Constraints" for more theorical evaluation of several line/arc search algorithms for quadratic functions. If memory is a problem, you could generate each row/column separately using sparse basis pursuit, for which there are many algorithms depending on the nature of your problem. See Qu, Sun and Wright (2015) "Finding a sparse vector in a subspace: linear sparsity using alternate directions" and Bian et al (2015) "Sparse null space basis pursuit and analysis dictionary learning for high-dimensional data analysis" for algorithm details, though in both cases you will have to incorporate/replace constraints to promote orthogonality to all previous vectors.

It's also worth noting there are sparse QR algorithms that return Q as the product of sparse/structured matrices. If you are concerned about storage space alone, this might be the simplest method to create large, efficient orthogonal operators.

Comment: The first idea really works, and it's awesome. But could you please specify function `f` in your second idea so that I understand it more clearly?